# GraphQL: Return a type with non-nullable id field as a query result

Tags: graphql, graphcool

I have this type:

```
  type Profile {
    id: ID! @isUnique
    email: String! @isUnique
    ...
  }
```

And a query:

```
profile(email: String!):Profile
```

When I run the query with a user that doesn't exist, my underlying resolver returns null and I was expecting GraphQL to like this.

But, I get this error:

```
Cannot return null for non-nullable field Profile.id.
```

This happens because the query is expected to return a `Profile` and a `Profile` must have `id` field.

But, the query's return type is not non-nullable `Profile!`, it is `Profile` which would mean the query might return nothing.

How to fix this properly?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the full response from GraphQL, not just the error?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, here you have my full response

https://justpaste.it/4pqlr

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `null` in your profile query resolver. If you return something like an empty object, the Profile resolver will pick that up and attempt to return `undefined` as `Profile.id`, which as you noted is a schema error.

Try something like this:

```
const queryProfileResolver = (_, { email }) => {
  // getProfileByEmail should return null if no match is found
  return getProfileByEmail(email)
}
```

your graphQL response will then look something like this

```
{
  data: {
    profile: null
  }
}
```

Comment: Same problem, not solution :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to drop your data base and use 
`types.graphql` as it is

```
type Profile {
    id: ID! @isUnique
    email: String! @isUnique 
    ...
  }
```

deploy it and error would be gone.

**Main reason for happening this is you've already deployed data with not null thus it can't changed you need to drop our database, that's it**